# directory not defined when looping through json file with node js

Tags: json, node.js

I am getting an error that "directory is not defined" I really don't know if it means in my code or my json file. Here is the json file which I checked the format with  https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

```
    [
    {
    "directory": "C:\\Users\\PCAdmin\\Downloads\\jsonin",
    "dirID": "dir01"
    },
    {
    "directory": "C:\\Users\\PCAdmin\\Downloads\\jsonout",
    "dirID": "dir02"
    }
    ]
```

Here is my code which based on examples I've seen should work yet I can't seem to get past the error;

```
    'use strict';
    var fs = require('fs'); 
    var jsonObj = require("./jsonDirectories.json");
    for(directory in jsonObj) {
      console.log("Dir: "+jsonObj.directory);
    }
```

I'm sure it's something stupid but any direction would be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through array in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Try this. console.log("Dir: "+directory.directory); . You might want to use good naming conventions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that the variable `directory` on line 4 of your code was not initialized. The following code will fix that bug:

```
'use strict';
var fs = require('fs'); 
var jsonObj = require("./jsonDirectories.json");
for (var dirInfo in jsonObj) {
    console.log("Dir: " + dirInfo.directory);
}
```

However, this still does not do what you want, because the `in` operator does not work this way for arrays. The `in` operator is generally used to get the keys of objects (and then [should still be used carefully](https://jslinterrors.com/the-body-of-a-for-in-should-be-wrapped-in-an-if-statement)).

To loop over your array of directory info, what you want is the following:

```
'use strict';
var fs = require('fs'); 
var jsonObj = require('./jsonDirectories.json');
jsonObj.forEach(function(dirInfo) {
    console.log('Dir: '+dirInfo.directory);
}
```

(I also removed the mixed single and double quotes, which is good practice.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to [declare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) the `directory` variable before using it:

```
for (let item of jsonObj) {
  // This line also needed fixing:
  console.log("Dir: ", item.directory);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use `for(directory in jsonObj)` in node.js, directory will be assigned to the index of each of the items, not the value. so you can use `jsonObj[directory]` to get the directory.

But in my mind, this alternative is better:

```
jsonObj.forEach( function(directory) { 
  console.log("Dir: "+ directory);
});
```